# Saving selected date and time into a plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, plist, uidatepicker

I would like to know how to save a selected date and time from a date picker into a plist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [userArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyy hh:mm a"];         
[dict setObject:[dateformatter stringFromDate:date] forKey:@"LastLocalDataUpdate"];
[userArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: According to Apple docs NSUserDefaults can store instances of NSDate so converting the date to a string isn't necessary, see Jack Humphries' solution below.

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` is good enough for what you're trying to do:

```
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate date];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:theDate forKey:@"Date"];
```

Comment: You really shouldn't stuff arbitrary data into User Defaults. It's intended to only be used for application preferences and settings.

Answer (score 0):

[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will do it just [nicely](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults).

Comment: You really shouldn't stuff arbitrary data into User Defaults. It's intended to only be used for application preferences and settings.

Comment: Based on the very little information he gave it seems like NSUserDefaults is what he wants.  He wanted to save it to a plist and because (usually) you don't change a date picker very often NSUserDefaults is the way to go.